# Find the probability of $P(\overline{Z}<0.5)$.

Tags: probability

Consider independent random variables $Z_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,16$ be standard normal distributed, and let $\overline{Z}$ be sample mean.

Find: $P(\overline{Z}<0.5)$.

I try as below.

$\overline{Z}=\dfrac{Z_1+...+Z_{16}}{16}$

$P(\overline{Z}<0.5)=P(Z_1+...+Z_{16}<8)$.

Now I don't know how to find $P(Z_1+...+Z_{16}<8)$. I confused to determining the probability, because I don't know what the theorem be used to calculate this probability.

Anyone can give me hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\overline Z$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\frac  1 {16}$.